# How to show an svg image?

Tags: xamarin.forms

How to show an svg image in xamarin.forms? I have an cross platform project where png works great instead of svg. In my solution I have UWP,iOS,Android and I add macOs as well.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using scalabe svg files in Xamarin with the svg plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47817097/using-scalabe-svg-files-in-xamarin-with-the-svg-plugin)

Comment: please search before posting - there are many existing questions that address this same issue